# How to send one sql row per second through a socket io connection?

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, socket.io

I created a node.js server and am now trying to send my mysql data from a table to a browser (with a javascript client receiving the data).

My problem is that if I want to send all of the rows from my table, it works fine, but if I want to send just one row per second, it doesn't work.

This is what I am doing:
server side:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  for (var i = 1; i < 60; i++) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM jsonlines WHERE id="'+i+'"').on('result', function(data) {
      // Push results onto the notes array
      var a=  JSON.stringify(data);
      notes.push(a); //I want to save each line in an array notes

      setTimeout(function() {
        socket.emit('news', notes[i]);
        console.log(a);
      }, (1 * 1000));
    });
  }

 });
```

So basicaly I have an id in my table that is different for each row and, am selecting the rows in a for loop.
Settimeout serves to do a 1 second delay so that the socket.emit() only sends my data 1 second after the query has been done.

However, `console.log(a)` print all my rows imidiatelly, with the delay.

What am I doing wrong?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you gat any exceptions?

Comment: @Tomasito665, no, the code works. The problem is that when I do a `console.log(a)` inside the function, I get every value of my table immediately, without any 1 second delay.
I will include that in my question.

Comment: Can you try replacing your code with this: http://pastebin.com/e8EvP5rV What does `console.log(endTime - startTime);` output? Just curious if the setTimeout even works.

Comment: you should probably delete mysql tag from your question, it is mostly about js itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should always keep in mind that js is asynchronous.

That means your loop `for(var i=1;i<60;i++){` will continue looping after `setTimeout` call.

So to get delay your next call should wait until previous is done.

You can try this attempt, just to see the difference:

```
var i = 60;
myFunc = function(socket) {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM jsonlines WHERE id="'+i+'"').on('result', function(data) {
          var a=  JSON.stringify(data);
          notes.push(a); 

          socket.emit('news',notes[i]);
          console.log(a);

          i--;
          console.log(i);
          dt = new Date();
          console.log(dt.getMinutes()+':'+dt.getSeconds());
          if (i > 0) {
              setTimeout(function(){myFunc(socket);}, 1000);
          }
  });

}

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    myFunc(socket);
});
```

**Another approach**

```
var i = 60;
var mySocket='';
myFunc = function() {
  connection.query('SELECT * FROM jsonlines WHERE id="'+i+'"').on('result', function(data) {
          var a=  JSON.stringify(data);
          notes.push(a); 

          mySocket.emit('news',notes[i]);
          console.log(a);

          i--;
          console.log(i);
          dt = new Date();
          console.log(dt.getMinutes()+':'+dt.getSeconds());
          if (i > 0) {
              setTimeout(function(){myFunc();}, 1000);
          }
  });

}


io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    mySocket = socket;
    myFunc();
});
```

Comment: Thank you Alex. I think you are on the right track, but if you notice in `myFunc` `socket` is not defined, so it doesn't work the way you wrote it. I will try and fix it.

Comment: so, just add socket as param

Comment: I did, but unfortunately it doesn't print anything in the console now

Comment: did you check my updated answer? post your current code please. and keep in mind I can not debug your code, since it is data and environement dependent

Answer (score 0):

Because of the asynchronous request, all the 60 queries are done approximately at the same time(assume db connecting and computing well).

Try this:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {

  for (var i = 1; i < 60; i++) {
    connection.query('SELECT * FROM jsonlines WHERE id="'+i+'"').on('result', function(data) {
      // Push results onto the notes array
      var a=  JSON.stringify(data);
      notes.push(a); //I want to save each line in an array notes

      setTimeout(function() {
        socket.emit('news', a); // variable 'i' will be 60, you should use variable 'a' directly                 
        console.log(a);
      }, (i * 1000));
    }); 
  }   

});
```